# literal and rvalue reference

Tags: c++11, rvalue

```
void test(int && val)
{
    val=4;
}

void main()
{  
    test(1);
    std::cin.ignore();    
}
```

Is a `int` is created when `test` is called or by default in c++ literals are `int` type?

Comment: Should that be `test(int & val)`?

Comment: under MSV10 in debug mode at least the code compile

Comment: `int &&` is an rvalue reference type, which is C++0x standard.

Comment: Yes, `1` is by default an `int`. If you want to change that then you can use suffixes like `u`, `l` or `ll`. E.g. `1ull` is an unsigned long long.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Note that your code would compile **only** with C++11 compiler.

When you pass an integral literal, which is by default of `int` type, unless you write `1L`, a *temporary object* of type `int` is created which is bound to the parameter of the function. It's like the *first* from the following initializations:

```
int &&      x = 1; //ok. valid in C++11 only.
int &       y = 1; //error, both in C++03, and C++11
const int & z = 1; //ok, both in C++03, and C++11
```

Answer (score 0):

An int with the value 1 is created when test is called.  Literals are typed by their form.  For example, 1 is an int, 1.0 is a double, "1" is a string.

Comment: `"1"` is a `char const[2]`.

Comment: That is very misleading, though.  The type of `"1"` is not "string" and there is no fundamental "string" type; if there was, then presumably `"1"` and `"11"` would have the same type but they do not.

Comment: I understand there is no fundamental string type; nonetheless, we all use them, discuss them and design with them everyday.  Hence the smiley.

Comment: Then your whole last part doesn't make sense. 1L is "an int" too, as in "an integer". Either you precisely mean what you say or you don't.

Comment: My goodness.  Take a breath, note the smiley indicating it wasn't a serious statement to begin with, and move on.