# What is the difference between long x = 32L and long const x = 32?

Tags: c++, types, primitive-types

I walked through a C++ book and I got a statement like this `long x = 32L` and given statement as   `l or L suffix on an integer means the integer is a type  long constant`; but when I check using compiler as `long x = 32L ; cout<<x; x = 45 ; cout<<x ;` then there is no error or warning so what constant mean here? Isn't long const  x =  32; ?

Comment: Just because `32L` is a constant, doesn't mean `x` is.

Comment: the value of the literal `32L` is copied in `x`. This assignment doesn't mean that `x` takes the `const` qualifier as a complement.

Comment: @Rhymoid Can you be more Specific ?

Comment: @Rhymoid `32L` is not `const`. In C, integer literals are called "constants", however in C++ they call them "literals" to avoid confusion between "constant" and `const` which are , unfortunately, different concepts.

Comment: @MattMcNabb Good addition, I wasn't clear in the distinction.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because OP didn't read his book properly.

Comment: @Griwes: More likely the book is bad/wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Whether or not `32L` is `const` doesn't matter ; when you write `long x = 32L;` then `x` is a variable whose value is copied from `32`.  `x` is certainly not `const`.  When you change `x` you are not changing the literal `32`; you are putting a new value into the variable `x`'s storage.

The technical term in C++ for `32` or `32L` is a *literal*. However, people sometimes call them "constants".  This is a bit confusing because it is nothing to do with what the keyword `const` does.

The only difference between `32` and `32L` is that one is `int` and the other is `long`.

Comment: "Whether or not `32L` is `const` doesn't matter" I guess it does, though. From my understanding, it's like saying "Whether or not Wednesday tastes blue doesn't matter": `const` only applies to lvalues (and perhaps effectful rvalues).

Comment: @Rhymoid well, every literal has a type; and every type is either const-qualified or not const-qualified (at the top level).  I can't think of a case right now where it makes a difference though.  Note that `(const int)32` is legal, and gives a const rvalue

Comment: C++11 supports literals of class type; in those cases it is actually important that the literal is not const, because you can call functions on the literal directly!

Comment: Well, I guess C++'s type system is more elaborate than I thought (the undecidability of reconstruction should've been a hint).

Comment: FWIW, you can do `int &&x = 5; x = 6;`, too.

Comment: @chris: [Oh, my](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bde4455534707a0c). This language is stupid.

Comment: I said it in chat, but [explanation](http://codepuppy.co.uk/cpptuts/Beginning/references.php).

Comment: @chris: [Apparently it's a temporary copy, at least](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6864955/560648)

Answer (score 0):

I think you're getting confused about what `L` is for. Consider a platform with 32 bit `int` and 64 bit `long` :

```
unsigned long i = 0xffffffff << 16;
```

This sets: `i <- 0xffff0000` since `0xffffffff` is implicitly an integer value, and the expression on the right is evaluated accordingly. On the other hand,

```
unsigned long i = 0xffffffffUL << 16;
```

yields: `i <- ffffffff0000`, as the expression is being evaluated as an unsigned long.

Answer (score 0):

In order a variable to be constant, it should be accompanied by the **const** keyword.

For example:

```
const int a = 5;
a = 6; // error
```

Now what you have, is that you assign a constant value, i.e. 32 in a variable. The constant goes to the value, not to the variable.

You do for example:

`a = 32L;`

so the value you assign to the variable `a` is a constant, `32L`.

If you did

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
   a = i;
```

then the value you assign to variable `a` is not a constant.

I *strongly* suggests you to take a look at my relative [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23629126/analysis-of-float-double-precision-in-32-decimal-digits) about the `L` that follows 32.

`What is the difference between long x = 32L and long const x = 32 ?`

The difference is that in the first, you can assign variable `x` a new value, where in the second you can not.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting confused with the terms.

According to this statement:

```
int x = 32;
```

**x** is a variable of the int type, and **32** is a literal of int type.

You can never do **32 = 35** , but you can do **x = 35** because **x** is not a constant.

According to this other statement:

```
const long y = 32L;
```

it means that **y** is a constant of type **long** and cannot be changed. Also, **32L** is a literal of type **long** and it cannot be changed either.

You can never do **y = 35L** because **y** is a constant and its value has been already set.

Moreover, just like @MattMcNabb sad:

> "The only difference between 32 and 32L is that one is int and the other is long."

Comment: To add to the answer, if you used **auto x=32**, it would create an int and if you used **auto y=32L**, it would create a long.

Comment: @cup `auto` is perhaps a bad example, because you'd never want to use it in a case like this.  On the other hand, given `template <typename T> void f( T param );`, `f( 32 )` will instantiate and call `f<int>`, and `f( 32L )` will instantiate and call `f<long>`.

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr: Yes, you're right.**

---

The book is calling it a "constant", but it is wrong; the correct term is "literal".

There is no way to modify the literal itself (which is probably why the book author used this term) but, once you use the literal to initialise `long int x`, `x` can be modified because it is not `const`.

You are right that `long int const x` would be the way to make the final "variable" actually be a constant.