# Behavioral differences in 5 vs std::move(5)

Tags: c++, c++14, xvalue, value-categories, prvalue

I've read all the major questions on SO about different value categories but still don't clearly understand the difference between, in this case, xvalues vs prvalues.

I know that, like all glvalues, xvalues can have their dynamic type different from the static one, but e.g. in case of literal vs `std::move` from literal I can't find 'real' behavioral differences (maybe apart from those that are formally based on what's xvalue and what's prvalue, like which constructor will get called in `MyClass(std::move(5))`; but it doesn't seem that important in case of literals since their values won't be used anyway.

What is the actual 'benefit' I can get from calling `std::move` on a literal?

Comment: You don't need to.  related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6864718/literal-and-rvalue-reference

Comment: _"What is the actual 'benefit' I ..."_: none as the contents of a literal can not be stolen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the actual 'benefit' I can get from calling `std::move` on a literal?

None. A (non-string) literal is a prvalue, which is an rvalue. Calling `std::move()` will give you an xvalue, but that is still an rvalue. There's no way to overload on the difference between xvalue and prvalue - you can only overload on the difference between lvalue and rvalue - so there's no subsequent difference.

However, if we generalize to calling `std::move` on a prvalue, there is one big anti-benefit: you lose temporary lifetime extension in some places where you might need it. Consider:

```
SomeContainer foo();
for (auto&& elem : foo()) { ... }
```

That works fine. You can iterate over a prvalue like that. However, this does not work at all:

```
SomeContainer foo();
for (auto&& elem : std::move(foo())) { ... }
```

We *still* have an rvalue of type `SomeContainer`, but now our temporary is bound to the reference parameter of `move()` so it goes out of scope before the body of the `for` loop is entered. Oops.

Comment: By the way, why wasn't `std::move` implemented as a cast? Since it actually is an unconditional cast to rvalue. I know it actually is implemented via `static_cast` but making it itself a separate kind of cast would help to eliminate issues you mentioned.

Comment: Not all literals are prvalues, even if we ignore user-defined literals. </pedantic>

Comment: @ledonter That solves a problem that only exists if you chose to write code that doesn't have any benefit. A simpler solution would be to just not write `move()` there.

Comment: @T.C. Edited :)